# Text manipulation with sed

Tags: html, bash, sed

I need a little help, in our class we've been playing around with GREP and SED commands in an attempt to learn how they work. More specifically we've been using sed commands to manipulate text and add tags.

So, we we're given an assignment, we've been given 500 lines of CSV fake data and it is our job to create a sed command that will automatically tag the data and tag any new data added down the road (theoretically).

***Here's a few lines of our fake UN-TAGGED data, this is by default how we received it, as you can see all the data starts with a first name and ends with a web email:***

```
FirstName,LastName,Company,Address,City,County,State,ZIP,Phone,Fax,Email,Web
"Essie","Vaill","Litronic Industries","14225 Hancock Dr","Anchorage","Anchorage","AK","99515","907-345-0962","907-345-1215","essie@vaill.com","http://www.essievaill.com"
"Cruz","Roudabush","Meridian Products","2202 S Central Ave","Phoenix","Maricopa","AZ","85004","602-252-4827","602-252-4009","cruz@roudabush.com","http://www.cruzroudabush.com"
"Billie","Tinnes","D & M Plywood Inc","28 W 27th St","New York","New York","NY","10001","212-889-5775","212-889-5764","billie@tinnes.com","http://www.billietinnes.com"
"Zackary","Mockus","Metropolitan Elevator Co","286 State St","Perth Amboy","Middlesex","NJ","08861","732-442-0638","732-442-5218","zackary@mockus.com","http://www.zackarymockus.com"
"Rosemarie","Fifield","Technology Services","3131 N Nimitz Hwy  #-105","Honolulu","Honolulu","HI","96819","808-836-8966","808-836-6008","rosemarie@fifield.com","http://www.rosemariefifield.com"
"Bernard","Laboy","Century 21 Keewaydin Prop","22661 S Frontage Rd","Channahon","Will","IL","60410","815-467-0487","815-467-1244","bernard@laboy.com","http://www.bernardlaboy.com"
"Sue","Haakinson","Kim Peacock Beringhause","9617 N Metro Pky W","Phoenix","Maricopa","AZ","85051","602-953-2753","602-953-0355","sue@haakinson.com","http://www.suehaakinson.com"
"Valerie","Pou","Sea Port Record One Stop Inc","7475 Hamilton Blvd","Trexlertown","Lehigh","PA","18087","610-395-8743","610-395-6995","valerie@pou.com","http://www.valeriepou.com"
"Lashawn","Hasty","Kpff Consulting Engineers","815 S Glendora Ave","West Covina","Los Angeles","CA","91790","626-960-6738","626-960-1503","lashawn@hasty.com","http://www.lashawnhasty.com"
"Marianne","Earman","Albers Technologies Corp","6220 S Orange Blossom Trl","Orlando","Orange","FL","32809","407-857-0431","407-857-2506","marianne@earman.com","http://www.marianneearman.com"
"Justina","Dragaj","Uchner, David D Esq","2552 Poplar Ave","Memphis","Shelby","TN","38112","901-327-5336","901-327-2911","justina@dragaj.com","http://www.justinadragaj.com"
"Mandy","Mcdonnell","Southern Vermont Surveys","343 Bush St Se","Salem","Marion","OR","97302","503-371-8219","503-371-1118","mandy@mcdonnell.com","http://www.mandymcdonnell.com"
"Conrad","Lanfear","Kahler, Karen T Esq","49 Roche Way","Youngstown","Mahoning","OH","44512","330-758-0314","330-758-3536","conrad@lanfear.com","http://www.conradlanfear.com"
"Cyril","Behen","National Paper & Envelope Corp","1650 S Harbor Blvd","Anaheim","Orange","CA","92802","714-772-5050","714-772-3859","cyril@behen.com","http://www.cyrilbehen.com"
"Shelley","Groden","Norton, Robert L Esq","110 Broadway St","San Antonio","Bexar","TX","78205","210-229-3017","210-229-9757","shelley@groden.com","http://www.shelleygroden.com"
```

***Our teacher wanted us to create sed commands that would automatically indent the data, add TR to the front and back of the data and add TD tags to each new field.***

```
<HTML>
<HEAD><Title>Lab 4b by Andrey</Title></HEAD>
<BODY>
<table border="1">
   <TR><TD>FirstName</TD><TD>LastName</TD><TD>Company</TD><TD>Address</TD><TD>City</TD><TD>County</TD><TD>State</TD><TD>ZIP</TD><TD>Phone</TD><TD>Fax</TD><TD>Email</TD><TD>Web</TD></TR>
   <TR><TD>Essie</TD><TD>Vaill</TD><TD>Litronic Industries</TD><TD>14225 Hancock Dr</TD><TD>Anchorage</TD><TD>Anchorage</TD><TD>AK</TD><TD>99515</TD><TD>907-345-0962</TD><TD>907-345-1215</TD><TD>essie@vaill.com</TD><TD>http://www.essievaill.com</TD><TR>
   <TR><TD>Cruz</TD><TD>Roudabush</TD><TD>Meridian Products</TD><TD>2202 S Central Ave</TD><TD>Phoenix</TD><TD>Maricopa</TD><TD>AZ</TD><TD>85004</TD><TD>602-252-4827</TD><TD>602-252-4009</TD><TD>cruz@roudabush.com</TD><TD>http://www.cruzroudabush.com</TD><TR>
   <TR><TD>Billie</TD><TD>Tinnes</TD><TD>D & M Plywood Inc</TD><TD>28 W 27th St</TD><TD>New York</TD><TD>New York</TD><TD>NY</TD><TD>10001</TD><TD>212-889-5775</TD><TD>212-889-5764</TD><TD>billie@tinnes.com</TD><TD>http://www.billietinnes.com</TD><TR>
   <TR><TD>Zackary</TD><TD>Mockus</TD><TD>Metropolitan Elevator Co</TD><TD>286 State St</TD><TD>Perth Amboy</TD><TD>Middlesex</TD><TD>NJ</TD><TD>08861</TD><TD>732-442-0638</TD><TD>732-442-5218</TD><TD>zackary@mockus.com</TD><TD>http://www.zackarymockus.com</TD><TR>
   <TR><TD>Rosemarie</TD><TD>Fifield</TD><TD>Technology Services</TD><TD>3131 N Nimitz Hwy  #-105</TD><TD>Honolulu</TD><TD>Honolulu</TD><TD>HI</TD><TD>96819</TD><TD>808-836-8966</TD><TD>808-836-6008</TD><TD>rosemarie@fifield.com</TD><TD>http://www.rosemariefifield.com<$
   <TR><TD>Bernard</TD><TD>Laboy</TD><TD>Century 21 Keewaydin Prop</TD><TD>22661 S Frontage Rd</TD><TD>Channahon</TD><TD>Will</TD><TD>IL</TD><TD>60410</TD><TD>815-467-0487</TD><TD>815-467-1244</TD><TD>bernard@laboy.com</TD><TD>http://www.bernardlaboy.com</TD><TR>
   <TR><TD>Sue</TD><TD>Haakinson</TD><TD>Kim Peacock Beringhause</TD><TD>9617 N Metro Pky W</TD><TD>Phoenix</TD><TD>Maricopa</TD><TD>AZ</TD><TD>85051</TD><TD>602-953-2753</TD><TD>602-953-0355</TD><TD>sue@haakinson.com</TD><TD>http://www.suehaakinson.com</TD><TR>
   <TR><TD>Valerie</TD><TD>Pou</TD><TD>Sea Port Record One Stop Inc</TD><TD>7475 Hamilton Blvd</TD><TD>Trexlertown</TD><TD>Lehigh</TD><TD>PA</TD><TD>18087</TD><TD>610-395-8743</TD><TD>610-395-6995</TD><TD>valerie@pou.com</TD><TD>http://www.valeriepou.com</TD><TR>
   <TR><TD>Lashawn</TD><TD>Hasty</TD><TD>Kpff Consulting Engineers</TD><TD>815 S Glendora Ave</TD><TD>West Covina</TD><TD>Los Angeles</TD><TD>CA</TD><TD>91790</TD><TD>626-960-6738</TD><TD>626-960-1503</TD><TD>lashawn@hasty.com</TD><TD>http://www.lashawnhasty.com</TD><T$
   <TR><TD>Marianne</TD><TD>Earman</TD><TD>Albers Technologies Corp</TD><TD>6220 S Orange Blossom Trl</TD><TD>Orlando</TD><TD>Orange</TD><TD>FL</TD><TD>32809</TD><TD>407-857-0431</TD><TD>407-857-2506</TD><TD>marianne@earman.com</TD><TD>http://www.marianneearman.com</TD$
   <TR><TD>Justina</TD><TD>Dragaj</TD><TD>Uchner David D Esq</TD><TD>2552 Poplar Ave</TD><TD>Memphis</TD><TD>Shelby</TD><TD>TN</TD><TD>38112</TD><TD>901-327-5336</TD><TD>901-327-2911</TD><TD>justina@dragaj.com</TD><TD>http://www.justinadragaj.com</TD><TR>
   <TR><TD>Mandy</TD><TD>Mcdonnell</TD><TD>Southern Vermont Surveys</TD><TD>343 Bush St Se</TD><TD>Salem</TD><TD>Marion</TD><TD>OR</TD><TD>97302</TD><TD>503-371-8219</TD><TD>503-371-1118</TD><TD>mandy@mcdonnell.com</TD><TD>http://www.mandymcdonnell.com</TD><TR>
   <TR><TD>Conrad</TD><TD>Lanfear</TD><TD>Kahler Karen T Esq</TD><TD>49 Roche Way</TD><TD>Youngstown</TD><TD>Mahoning</TD><TD>OH</TD><TD>44512</TD><TD>330-758-0314</TD><TD>330-758-3536</TD><TD>conrad@lanfear.com</TD><TD>http://www.conradlanfear.com</TD><TR>
   <TR><TD>Cyril</TD><TD>Behen</TD><TD>National Paper & Envelope Corp</TD><TD>1650 S Harbor Blvd</TD><TD>Anaheim</TD><TD>Orange</TD><TD>CA</TD><TD>92802</TD><TD>714-772-5050</TD><TD>714-772-3859</TD><TD>cyril@behen.com</TD><TD>http://www.cyrilbehen.com</TD><TR>
   <TR><TD>Shelley</TD><TD>Groden</TD><TD>Norton Robert L Esq</TD><TD>110 Broadway St</TD><TD>San Antonio</TD><TD>Bexar</TD><TD>TX</TD><TD>78205</TD><TD>210-229-3017</TD><TD>210-229-9757</TD><TD>shelley@groden.com</TD><TD>http://www.shelleygroden.com</TD><TR>
</table>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

So, I was messing around and I tired to create a few sed commands that would mimic the second output.

My first attempt was:

```
#!/bin/sh 
sed -e 's=^.*$=<TR><TD>&</TD></TR>=' input.csv
```

Unfortunately, this program only outputs something like this where I get TR TD at the beginning and end, but no TD tags inside:

```
<TR><TD>"Bryan","Rovell","All N All Shop","90 Hackensack St","East Rutherford","Bergen","NJ","07073","201-939-2788","201-939-9079","bryan@rovell.com","http://www.bryanrovell.com"</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>"Joey","Bolick","Utility Trailer Sales","7700 N Council Rd","Oklahoma City","Oklahoma","OK","73132","405-728-5972","405-728-5244","joey@bolick.com","http://www.joeybolick.com"</TD></TR>
```

I've also attempted to create individual seds to tag field, but instead I've only managed to tag each word, so I'm kinda stuck.

I'm partially on the right track, I think, but I need helping indenting and adding TD to the beginning & end of every field, along with TR to the beginning and end of each new column.

Comment: You could replace all `","` with `</TD><TD>` then you just need to deal with the `^"` and `"$` cases separately.

Comment: Even if I tried doing  sed -r 's/"/<TD>/g' input.csv then I would get <TD>name<TD>, I still don't know think I know how to make the first instance of " a TD and the second instance of " a </TD>

Comment: That's why I recommended replacing all `","` not all `"`

Comment: and tell to your teacher, than 100% correctly parsing CSV files isn't easy as  someone could think - e.g. not a job for an simple  `sed` command.

Comment: Yeah it's a bit of a mess, I don't understand who wrote this curriculum for an intro class. Anyway, so would I write something like: sed -r 's/","/<TD></TD>/g' input.csv cause I tried that and it didn't work, but once again I'm not sure how to go about changing each instance that way

Comment: @joeytwiddle gave you most of the answer. Do something like this `sed -e 's/^"/  <TR><TD>/; s/","/<\/TD><TD>/g; s/"$/<\/TD><\/TR>/;'`

Comment: Presumably your teacher has never met "Shelly Groden<SCRIPT src='//anonymous.net/xploit.js'>" http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: @JustinR What you last wrote will break because you are using `/` as the delimiter for sed. Go back to using `=` as the delimeter, or escape the inner `/` with `\/` like @tgo did.

Comment: @joeytwiddle I didn't know that one.  I wouldn't want to plan for it with sed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the main part of it:

```
$ sed -r 's:^"?:    <TR><TD>:; s:"?,"?:</TD><TD>:g; s:"?$:</TD></TR>:' file
    <TR><TD>FirstName</TD><TD>LastName</TD><TD>Company</TD><TD>Address</TD><TD>City</TD><TD>County</TD><TD>State</TD><TD>ZIP</TD><TD>Phone</TD><TD>Fax</TD><TD>Email</TD><TD>Web</TD></TR>
    <TR><TD>Essie</TD><TD>Vaill</TD><TD>Litronic Industries</TD><TD>14225 Hancock Dr</TD><TD>Anchorage</TD><TD>Anchorage</TD><TD>AK</TD><TD>99515</TD><TD>907-345-0962</TD><TD>907-345-1215</TD><TD>essie@vaill.com</TD><TD>http://www.essievaill.com</TD></TR>
    <TR><TD>Cruz</TD><TD>Roudabush</TD><TD>Meridian Products</TD><TD>2202 S Central Ave</TD><TD>Phoenix</TD><TD>Maricopa</TD><TD>AZ</TD><TD>85004</TD><TD>602-252-4827</TD><TD>602-252-4009</TD><TD>cruz@roudabush.com</TD><TD>http://www.cruzroudabush.com</TD></TR>
    <TR><TD>Billie</TD><TD>Tinnes</TD><TD>D & M Plywood Inc</TD><TD>28 W 27th St</TD><TD>New York</TD><TD>New York</TD><TD>NY</TD><TD>10001</TD><TD>212-889-5775</TD><TD>212-889-5764</TD><TD>billie@tinnes.com</TD><TD>http://www.billietinnes.com</TD></TR>
    <TR><TD>Zackary</TD><TD>Mockus</TD><TD>Metropolitan Elevator Co</TD><TD>286 State St</TD><TD>Perth Amboy</TD><TD>Middlesex</TD><TD>NJ</TD><TD>08861</TD><TD>732-442-0638</TD><TD>732-442-5218</TD><TD>zackary@mockus.com</TD><TD>http://www.zackarymockus.com</TD></TR>
    <TR><TD>Rosemarie</TD><TD>Fifield</TD><TD>Technology Services</TD><TD>3131 N Nimitz Hwy  #-105</TD><TD>Honolulu</TD><TD>Honolulu</TD><TD>HI</TD><TD>96819</TD><TD>808-836-8966</TD><TD>808-836-6008</TD><TD>rosemarie@fifield.com</TD><TD>http://www.rosemariefifield.com</TD></TR>
    <TR><TD>Bernard</TD><TD>Laboy</TD><TD>Century 21 Keewaydin Prop</TD><TD>22661 S Frontage Rd</TD><TD>Channahon</TD><TD>Will</TD><TD>IL</TD><TD>60410</TD><TD>815-467-0487</TD><TD>815-467-1244</TD><TD>bernard@laboy.com</TD><TD>http://www.bernardlaboy.com</TD></TR>
    <TR><TD>Sue</TD><TD>Haakinson</TD><TD>Kim Peacock Beringhause</TD><TD>9617 N Metro Pky W</TD><TD>Phoenix</TD><TD>Maricopa</TD><TD>AZ</TD><TD>85051</TD><TD>602-953-2753</TD><TD>602-953-0355</TD><TD>sue@haakinson.com</TD><TD>http://www.suehaakinson.com</TD></TR>
    <TR><TD>Valerie</TD><TD>Pou</TD><TD>Sea Port Record One Stop Inc</TD><TD>7475 Hamilton Blvd</TD><TD>Trexlertown</TD><TD>Lehigh</TD><TD>PA</TD><TD>18087</TD><TD>610-395-8743</TD><TD>610-395-6995</TD><TD>valerie@pou.com</TD><TD>http://www.valeriepou.com</TD></TR>
    <TR><TD>Lashawn</TD><TD>Hasty</TD><TD>Kpff Consulting Engineers</TD><TD>815 S Glendora Ave</TD><TD>West Covina</TD><TD>Los Angeles</TD><TD>CA</TD><TD>91790</TD><TD>626-960-6738</TD><TD>626-960-1503</TD><TD>lashawn@hasty.com</TD><TD>http://www.lashawnhasty.com</TD></TR>
    <TR><TD>Marianne</TD><TD>Earman</TD><TD>Albers Technologies Corp</TD><TD>6220 S Orange Blossom Trl</TD><TD>Orlando</TD><TD>Orange</TD><TD>FL</TD><TD>32809</TD><TD>407-857-0431</TD><TD>407-857-2506</TD><TD>marianne@earman.com</TD><TD>http://www.marianneearman.com</TD></TR>
    <TR><TD>Justina</TD><TD>Dragaj</TD><TD>Uchner</TD><TD> David D Esq</TD><TD>2552 Poplar Ave</TD><TD>Memphis</TD><TD>Shelby</TD><TD>TN</TD><TD>38112</TD><TD>901-327-5336</TD><TD>901-327-2911</TD><TD>justina@dragaj.com</TD><TD>http://www.justinadragaj.com</TD></TR>
    <TR><TD>Mandy</TD><TD>Mcdonnell</TD><TD>Southern Vermont Surveys</TD><TD>343 Bush St Se</TD><TD>Salem</TD><TD>Marion</TD><TD>OR</TD><TD>97302</TD><TD>503-371-8219</TD><TD>503-371-1118</TD><TD>mandy@mcdonnell.com</TD><TD>http://www.mandymcdonnell.com</TD></TR>
    <TR><TD>Conrad</TD><TD>Lanfear</TD><TD>Kahler</TD><TD> Karen T Esq</TD><TD>49 Roche Way</TD><TD>Youngstown</TD><TD>Mahoning</TD><TD>OH</TD><TD>44512</TD><TD>330-758-0314</TD><TD>330-758-3536</TD><TD>conrad@lanfear.com</TD><TD>http://www.conradlanfear.com</TD></TR>
    <TR><TD>Cyril</TD><TD>Behen</TD><TD>National Paper & Envelope Corp</TD><TD>1650 S Harbor Blvd</TD><TD>Anaheim</TD><TD>Orange</TD><TD>CA</TD><TD>92802</TD><TD>714-772-5050</TD><TD>714-772-3859</TD><TD>cyril@behen.com</TD><TD>http://www.cyrilbehen.com</TD></TR>
    <TR><TD>Shelley</TD><TD>Groden</TD><TD>Norton</TD><TD> Robert L Esq</TD><TD>110 Broadway St</TD><TD>San Antonio</TD><TD>Bexar</TD><TD>TX</TD><TD>78205</TD><TD>210-229-3017</TD><TD>210-229-9757</TD><TD>shelley@groden.com</TD><TD>http://www.shelleygroden.com</TD></TR>
```

I expect you can figure out the rest since that's just printing the head and tail lines.